# Messing up import file path

Tags: javascript, node.js

This feels like such a dumb question, but I feel like I'm going crazy because I can't figure out what's wrong, everything seems fine.

This is the relevant part of my file path:

```
methods
-clickElement.js
-getIdentifier.js
-index.js
```

I'm trying to import getIdentifier into clickElement.

Inside clickElement:

```
const { getIdentifier } = require('.');
const clickElement = (driver, type, identifier) => {
//code
};
module.exports = { clickElement };
```

Inside index:

```
const { clickElement } = require('./clickElement.js');
const { getIdentifier } = require('./getIdentifier.js');
module.exports = { clickElement, getIdentifier };
```

Inside getIdentifier:

```
const getIdentifier = (type, identifier) => {
  // code
};

module.exports = { getIdentifier };
```

I get the error that getIdentifier is not a function at clickElement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a circular dependency there. Outside of your `methods` directory, you can simply `require('./methods')` and have access to both methods contained therein. However, if one method depends on the other, you have to access that file directly. Try this:

```js
const { getIdentifier } = require('./getIdentifier');
const clickElement = (driver, type, identifier) => {
//code
};
module.exports = { clickElement };
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try:

`const { getIdentifier } = require('./getIdentifier.js');`

Instead of:

`const { getIdentifier } = require('.');`

In `clickElement`.